# Setting the width of an article in Javascript doesn't update

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have this code for a canvas and a chat:

```
<section id="main_section">
        <article id="GL">
            <canvas id="GL-Surface">

            </canvas>
        </article>

        <article id="chat">
            <script src="chat.js"></script>
        </article>
</section>
```

I want to set the width and height of the chat. It works when setting it in CSS, but I want to change the size of the chat inside of Javascript, since the canvas might get bigger. I use these commands to set the size:

```
document.getElementById("chat").width = w;
document.getElementById("chat").height = h;
```

But the chat doesn't change the size. These lines work for changing the size of the article containing the canvas. Printing out the `document.getElementById("chat").width` returns the right value, which is weird.

What is going on, that the same commands only work for some objects?

Comment: You want `document.getElementById("chat").style.width = w`, etc

Comment: I don't see any nesting of script tags - just one script (nested inside an `<article>` which is weird but won't stop the script working). The issue is just that the OP is assigning to a property that has no meaning in the DOM. I already gave the fix in my first comment.

Comment: what values of `w` and `h` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have set the width and height in your CSS, you can only modify the style properties of the canvas to change it, i.e. `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height`.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.style.width = "500px";
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: @user11914177 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` tag doesn't belong there - it may know what the `#gl` element is, but it may not know what `#chat` is if the script executes *before* `#chat` gets defined by closing the article tag.

Move it to the bottom of the body.

Comment: Thanks for that advice